# Select subset of an array in jsonb postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres 9.6.3:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Records"
(
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "Json" jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Records" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
```

Inside my "Json" column i store arrays like so:

```
[
  {"a":"b0","c":0,"z":true}, 
  {"a":"b1","c":1,"z":false},  
  {"a":"b2","c":2,"z":true}
]
```

There can be some 10 million entries in each array, and there can be some 5 million records in the table.

I want to get the JSON out, paged, e.g. skip 1 record and return 2 records.

I can do it like so:

```
select string_agg(txt, ',') as x FROM 
(select jsonb_array_elements_text("Json") as txt 
FROM "Records" where "Id" = 'de70aadc-70e8-4c77-bd4b-af75ed36897e' -- some id here
limit 50 offset 5000 -- paging parameters
) s;
```

However, the query takes almost a second (between 780 and 900 msec) to run on my dev laptop with some quite decent hardware (macbook pro 2017).  Note: the timing is for the data sizes specified above, of course the sample data of 3 records returns faster.

Adding a GIN index like so: `CREATE INDEX records_gin ON "Records" USING gin ("Json");` didn't actually do anything for the query performance (i suppose because i am not querying by the contents of the array).

Is there any way to make this work faster?

Comment: If you **always** need a subset of the array, this might be a rare case of using an `jsonb[]` array. In that case you can use the native array syntax: `some_col[2:10]` to select a part of the array

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that doesn't work so well because that requires me to lose JSON syntax in favor of the native postgresql array syntax `{'JSON HERE','JSON HERE}`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be faster if you normalized your data and stored the array elements in a second table.  Then you could use [*keyset pagination*](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) to page through the data.

[image: no OFFFSET!]

Comment: That would impede my other use case of selecting ALL the data in one go as a string

Comment: Would it slow you down considerably? You can either optimize a data model for analytic queries that select everything (denormalize) or for queries that select only a few values.

Comment: Well at 10 million rows in the new table * 5 million records in the first table i am somewhat worried about performance. I will try to load test that.

Comment: You could partition the table if it grows too large, ideally along the `id` column (batch several `id`s in one partition to keep the number of partitions reasonable). Don't you run OOM handling a 5 million entry JSONB?

Comment: well one entry of 10 million small rows is just a few hundred megs when already serialized? I never download all 10 mils of all 5 mils ;)

Comment: The hard limit for a JSON value in the database is 1GB, so "just a few hundred megs" is already quite a lot, particularly since it will sit in RAM in its entirety when it is processed.

Comment: do you have more info or some links on the last point (loading the whole field to RAM)?

Comment: And re: keyset pagination - does that even work with guid keys? What if records actually have no keys? (See data in my post)

Comment: Keyset pagination works with every key that can be ordered. In this case, you would use it for the key of the new (big) table, and than need not be an UUID. I have no link for the RAM usage, but if the value is retrieved (detoasted), it certainly has to sit in RAM.

Comment: but that is only happens when i fet h the whole record?

Comment: No, also if you fetch only a part.

Comment: The keyset pagination did not work with `uuid` primary key, not with `ORDER BY` clause. I got some random set of values some 600 off where i was if used `offset`. The performance of the separate table on read is about 4.5 times faster, however if i need to delete the 10 million entries inside JSON, that is deleting one row, whereas here it is deleting 10 million and takes substantially longer.

Comment: Hm, you must have made some mistake with the pagination. Did you include the primary key in the WHERE condition? It is good that you test the different options, that way you can find what is best for you.